# is there an alternative to the Internet Developer Toolbar for IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Does anyone know of an alternative to the **[Internet Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en)** for IE7 that I can use for dom browsing and css debugging? I've used Firebug in the past and the IDT seemed anemic in comparison. It also seemed to crash my browser a lot.

OR: Has the IDT for IE7 improved to the point that it's almost as good as Firebug?

Update: shortly after writing this I started using the Developer Toolbar. Well, that's a strong term. I *tried* to use it. It's not working at all. Specifically I needed Select Element By Click and it won't do a damn thing. All the menu options are grayed out even after restarting IE7. Good thing I asked this question, looks like the IDT is just as buggy as I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debug Bar](http://www.debugbar.com/) is pretty nice, and is free for personal use. You have to pay for it if using commercially though.

**Update:** I should add that it did crash once or twice when there was some fairly advanced javascript. Didn't kill the entire browser but the toolbar was rendered useless until I restarted IE.

Comment: Veddy niiice. Installed and it works right away. Site license is a bit much for me to get mgmt to swallow though, especially with IE8 around the corner.

Comment: The find element by click doesn't work very well for my page; it's only able to find elements that are in a small section of the page.

Comment: From reading the details on the website and watching the video, it looks like a really basic product starving for advanced features, especially if you're gonna charge money for it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Firebug Lite : http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Comment: Won't work: "Insert this line of code into any page that you want to contain Firebug lite:" <-- no way that's gonna fly with the team

Comment: You can also run it as a bookmarklet, perhaps you could give that a try?

Comment: By the way, this is incredible for debugging IE! On their site they have a bookmarklet option.  Working great, even for AJAX scenarios!

Answer (score 0):

IE7 hasn't. But IE8 has. The developer tools included in Beta 2 and RC1 are very, very good. Well above the level of Firebug.

Comment: Won't work for me, I'm stuck with IE7 for at least the next few months. I'd prefer that MS fixed the software it released rather than just releasing a new one (with new bugs I presume).

Comment: But I think the Developer Toolbar is kind of an unsupported piece of software made by an intern at MS so it's not "official" enough to have bug fixes.

Comment: It has a JS profiler, which is very nice. Beyond that, can you explain how it is well above the level of Firebug?

Comment: Well, for starters it doesn't bring down the browser as Firebug is sometimes wont to do. Technically, I like the fact that it will debug all JS (including script inside handlers), allows inserting watch variables, will debug compatibility issues across versions, etc.

Comment: This is just not true (at least anymore here in 2011). IE Developer Toolbar is worthless in debugging AJAX scenarios. It doesn't show any of the styles that were applied when brought down asynchronously (same with trying to see javascript files brought down via AJAX). Also you have to manually hit the little Refresh icon after any AJAX calls to get a real-time view of the DOM. Both Firebug and Chrome's webkit tools are superior in this regard.

Comment: It's an old answer, but I agree with @mkmurray. It's 2013 and IE 8 dev tools still does not hold water against Firefox or Chrome dev tools. I didn't know about that little refresh button for getting updated DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have the latest version of the toolbar. I used to use a version prior to the one I now use, and the older version did crash IE7 quite a bit.

As far as features go, it would help to know what you feel you're missing. Having a lot of features isn't the same as having a lot of features you use.

Comment: mostly I'm looking for one that doesn't crash and burn all the time and works in IE7; beyond that I don't need much; if it had 90% of firebugs features and worked in IE7 I'd be happy

Comment: Go to the MS site and get the latest version then. Since my last update I've not had it crash (watch, now that I've posted that...) I use it at work all the time since we're supposed to be IE-only (long story, don't ask)